# Fork and Pull React-Router

Tags: javascript, npm, reactjs, react-router

I want to fork https://github.com/rackt/react-router to a private repo, update it, and then require it in my own project.

If I run

```
npm install react-router
```

It doesn't just give me what's in the github repo (it runs some build scripts and packages it nicely).

What's the best way to emulate this workflow?

Ideally I want to ...

1. Fork react-router from their repo to my private repo
2. Make changes locally and push to my private repo
3. npm install (my forked version) in some app

If I try to npm install {username}/react-router now, it installs the entire forked github repo (not built) and doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. there's a fork button on github.com, so that's not really a problem.
2. still not a problem.
3. this is easily done, but you need to tell npm to install from the right location: `npm install <<your fork's URL>>`

Using `npm install react-router` won't work (I would say obviously so), because `npm` already knows about the `react-router` package: it's right there on npmjs.com, pointing to [the official version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router).

If you want to install custom forks or even specific commits, install packages from the specific git URL you need.

So the specific steps you'd use are:

**done once**

1. fork the project to your own account on github.com
2. clone your own copy to your local machine
3. `npm install` in your local copy so you have everything necessary installed for building react-router

Then to change things:

**done constantly**

1. modify all the code you want to modify
2. build react-router with these updates using `npm run build`
3. git add, git commit, and git push you modified code and new build up to your own fork on github.com

And in your project that wants to *use* your personal flavour of react-router, you'd install your copy as:

`npm install username/react-router#yourmodifiedbranch`

(don't make this "master", always keep that in sync with the upstream master branch)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I am forking on Github. I'm not installing via npm install react-router. I said I'm installing {username}/react-router (my fork name), so it would be more like ...

npm install my-username/react-router

this seems to be the correct way to install it. I've also used the https github url.

what I don't get is how to build the install after I do it. if you do an npm install react-router, it doesn't look it just copies the react-router repo. It does a special build process.

Comment: If i try to run npm run build from the fork, I have to do an npm install inside the node_modules/react-router folder to get all the dependencies, it still errors.

Comment: you should definitely not need to. your fork, before modifications, is going to be identical to the official release, including the package.json dependencies and devDependencies. As such, `npm install yourgitrepo` should install in exactly the same way as the normal react-router

Comment: If i go here https://github.com/rackt/react-router and look at the files / folder structure and compare it to what i get inside node_modules/react-router after an npm install, it's completely different. sorry if i'm not understanding. the fork is identical to the release, but if i install via either npm install tarball url, or npm install username/repo-name i get the contents of the repo. not the 'built' version.

Comment: yes of course. What you get when you fork React, and what you get when you install react as a dependency, are different files. The first is "all the files react-router for development purposes", it's what you see on github. The second is "only those files that you need to use react-router in a deployment setup" and is controlled by package.json and npmignore instructions.

Comment: okay I think I get what you're saying now (finally). I ended up forking, then checking out a new branch with just the built files, and then running npm install username/react-router#branch. i'll try adding a postinstall hook in package.json to build + remove non-necessary / move build files

Comment: not quite. I've extended the answer with the steps involved.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run react-router's build step in your fork, then run `npm publish` from the `build/` directory, not the root directory.

```
npm install
npm run build
cd build/
npm publish --access=public
```

This is what gets published to npm: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/build